# How to guard against an undefined API call value in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, undefined

I have a component that makes an API call and returns some financial data set as state like so:

```
      const [statisticsData, setStatisticsData] = useState({});
```

which works perfectly, however, the API does not always have all of the data I need to display. A basic example of the JSX attempting to be rendered:

```
    <StatBox
        statType="PE Ratio"
        statValue={statisticsData.summaryDetail.PERatio.fmt}
      />
```

The component renders perfectly when the PE Ratio is defined by the API call, however the API does not always produce a PE ratio. I have tried using a ternary operator to check if `statisticsData.summaryDetail.PERatio.fmt` is defined, which did not work. I'm also not even able to get the typeof `statisticsData.summaryDetail.PERatio.fmt` as it throws a runtime error saying

> 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'fmt' of undefined'.

How can I guard against undefined values if the undefined value throws a runtime error before I can even check if it's undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case refactor the component like bellow

```
<StatBox
    statType="PE Ratio"
    statValue={statisticsData?.summaryDetail?.PERatio?.fmt ?? null}
/>
```

**??** is an operator that identify if the left hand side is **undefined** and then returns the right hand side. So the the **fmt** or **PERatio** is not defined it will pass **null**. Now handle the null value inside the component accordingly or pass any default value if you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
<StatBox
    statType="PE Ratio"
    statValue={statisticsData?.summaryDetail?.PERatio?.fmt}
/>
```

**? operator** checks if the value exists then it goes inside the object otherwise return undefined ***there is no need for ?? null***

> in your example statisticsData?.summaryDetail if 'statisticsData' is
> null then it wont go to 'summaryDetail' if it exists then it will go
> 'PERatio' and so on.

Comment: Sometime we might need to pass default value to the component that's why showed him the example how to pass other value on undefined

Comment: optional chaining doesn't return null if there is no value . It returns `undefined` . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining . so we need to use `??` . With your solution in place the author has to do this

`const StatsBox = ({ statValue = null }) =>  `